# Ajax won't submit and store information in database?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Creating a register.html form where the user is prompt to enter a name, email and password, then clicks submit which triggers a php script to check is the email enter is already in use, and if it is not already in use, it places the users data in the appropriate fields in the table 'users-form' on mysql.

My issue is that AJAX isn't submitting the form. The javascript that states "Fill in empty fields" works fines. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reg Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div>Register form</div>
    </div>
    <form action="">
      <p> Enter name, email and password</p>
      <label>Name :</label>
      <input id="name" type="text">
      <label>Email :</label>
      <input id="email" type="text">
      <label>Password :</label>
      <input id="password" type="password">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>

    //Internal Javascript
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
          var name = $("#name").val();
          var email = $("#email").val();
          var password = $("#password").val();
          //success message when information is stored in database.
          var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&email1=' + email + '&password1=' + password;
          if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '') {
            alert("Fill in empty fields");
          } else {
            //submits form
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "connect.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
              }
            });
          }
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

AJAX connect.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server..
$db = mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $connection); // Selecting Database
//Fetching Values from URL
$name2=$_POST['name1'];
$email2=$_POST['email1'];
$password2=$_POST['password1'];

//Insert query
$query = mysql_query("insert into users-form(name, email, password) values ('$name2', '$email2', '$password2')");
echo "Submitted!";
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reg Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <script src="js/theme.init.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="header">            
    <div>Register form</div>        
    </div>      

    <form action="" id="form">
    <p> Enter name, email and password</p>

    <label>Name :</label>
    <input id="name" name="name1" type="text">

    <label>Email :</label>
    <input id="email" name="email1" type="text" required>

    <label>Password :</label>
    <input id="password" name="password1" type="password" required>

    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>

    //Internal Javascript

                                    <script type="text/javascript">

                                    $(document).ready(function (e){
                                    $("#form").on('submit',(function(e){

                                        e.preventDefault();

                                            $.ajax({
                                            url: "connect.php ",
                                            type: "POST",
                                            data:  new FormData(this),
                                            contentType: false,
                                            cache: false,
                                            processData:false,
                                            success: function(result) {
                                            alert(result);
                                            }           

                                            });
                                            return false

                                    }));


                                    });
                        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately. Also removes the javascript check for empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your `javascript` code is fine the problem is `mysql` has deprecated instead you can use `mysqli` so your connection could be something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");


$name2=$_POST['name1'];
$email2=$_POST['email1'];
$password2=$_POST['password1'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "insert into `users-form` (name, email, password) values ('$name2', '$email2', '$password2')");

if ($query) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Comment: This is not working. I have a feeling it made be the mysqli_connect("localhost"...) line. Here is mysql  details: Server: localhost »Database: mydatabase »Table: users-form.

Comment: this code is working perfectly you just need to adjust the connection to your credentials for the database for example `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","your_username","your_password","mydatabase");`

Comment: This is the connect.php code with the changes suggested:

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","mydatabase","mydatabase","mydatabase");
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
      echo "connected";
  }

//Insert query
$query = mysqli_query($con, "insert into users-form(name, email, password) values ('$name2', '$email2', '$password2')");
echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";
mysqli_close($con); // Connection Closed
?>

Comment: remove `or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');` from your code  and try to submit your form and tell me what error you get.

Comment: I get no message at all. It does nothing. :(

Comment: Look @MechroMancer I've tried your code on my local host and it's working fine. i think it has something to do with your connection. did you name your database and username and password `mydatabase` as you have mentioned?

Comment: Yeah I did. I have done everything you have suggested.

Comment: I will update my answer and post all the php code give me a second.

Comment: @MechroMancer You were Right my code was buggy I apologize about that. but now it is working fine. just add your table name inside `` so it will be `  `users-form`  `

Comment: Didn't work. It must be a connection problem on my end.